# How to stream mp4 video from server using ExoPlayer?

Tags: android, video-streaming, exoplayer

recently i come across google exoplayer which has some cool feture with lack of documentation and support and am new to it , my doubt is how to play mp4 video using server URL. Now let me explain what I have tried so far

1. I have successfully implemented exoplayer in my project and make it works
2. But my problem is using my server url first it completes full video buffer then only it starts playing so it takes time ? what i need is it need to play simultaneously after getting each response so that video can be play it fast how can i achieve this. Now let me post what i have tried so far:

   ```
       BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
       TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);

       TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
       LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();
       player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, loadControl);
       simpleExoPlayerView = new SimpleExoPlayerView(this);
       simpleExoPlayerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view);
       simpleExoPlayerView.setUseController(true);
       simpleExoPlayerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus();
       simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);

       Log.d("url", intent.getStringExtra("videopath") + "?api_key=" + getResources().getString(R.string.dream_factory_api_key) + "&session_token=" + PreferenceUtils.getInstance(this).getStrData(PreferenceUtils.SESSION_TOKEN));
       MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(intent.getStringExtra("videopath") + "?api_key=" + getResources().getString(R.string.fs) + "&session_token=" + PreferenceUtils.getInstance(this).getStrData(PreferenceUtils.SESSION_TOKEN)),
               new CacheDataSourceFactory(this, 100 * 1024 * 1024, 5 * 1024 * 1024), new DefaultExtractorsFactory(), null, null);
       player.prepare(mediaSource);
   ```

Any help ? am i doing it in right way ? what i need is it needs buffer like youtube play and buffer not like buffer completely then play , Thanks in adavance

Comment: Try with DefaultDataSourceFactory replacing CacheDataSourceFactory

Comment: still not working

Comment: how did u play mp4 link in exoplayer?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of ExtractorMediaSource you should probably use DashMediaSource. That is for what you exactly want (buffering while playing).